# push request from one bucket to another bucket

Tags: github, bitbucket, github-actions, bitbucket-aws-code-deploy

I want to push  my repositories from master branch of GitHub into Bitbucket branch except master branch in bibucket as master branch is used by other customers, so we have to create push request from github master branch to bitucket branch except master branch in bitbucket.

Comment: Did you take a look at those bitbucket actions: https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=bitbucket ?

Comment: Thanks GuiFalourd,  want to push my repositories from master branch of GitHub into another brnach other then master branch in Bitbucket, is there any steps we can follow on prod env copying all the  repositories from github to bitubucket in another branch except master branch in bitbucket.

Comment: Also want to keep all  copies in the repositories in master branch.

Comment: Do you want to do it only one time, or every time the Github Repo is updated?

Comment: at present  one time copy of all the repositories from master branch github to Bitbucket in new brnach except master branch in bitbucket...also if it would be everytime github repo is updated to bitbucket would be helpful, only not in master branch in bitbucket...as we have to directly on prod env, so if we have steps.

Comment: if you already have the bitbucket repository, you can use one of the actions I shared initially to mirror your github repo on a bitbucket repo for each new update (you just have to aboid updating the master branch on bitbucket through you github action workflow).

Comment: I want to create the bitbucket repostiory in another brnach first except master brnach, and then copy the repostiory from master brnach from github  to bitubcket in that repostiory what steps can be followed on prod env.